# Unhandled Exception in Microsoft Visual C Runtime

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception

This is the error I'm getting:

The procedure entry point '_except_handler4_common' could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

This occurs on a Windows XP SP3 system with Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2005 / 2008 installed, but does not occur on a system with the Visuial C++ Redistributable 2005 / 2008 / 2010 installed

My question:
Is the symbol/entry point '_except_handler4_common' existent in versions of the Visual C++ runtime prior to 2010, or is 2010 required in order to deal with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's required. Essentially, it really depends on which version you used to compile the program. If you've used Visual Studio 2010, then you'll need the matching runtime files (unless you linked it statically).

Comment: I'm not the one who compiled the program - the program in question is [StackApplet](http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-version-1-5) for Windows, I know the dev, and i'll touch base with him to find what version he built the program in, but for those who don't know the dev, how would they find out which version of VC++ was used to build the program?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but tools like Dependency Walker should be able to tell you the libraries being used. But other than that, it's the developer's/publisher's responsibility.